# If humans adapted to survive car crashes what would our physiology be like?

Tags: biology, physics, bio-mechanics, vehicles

A good scenario for this situation would be roads got more dangerous and cars were not improving for more people  to survive car crashes. in this world they became more common. what would our physiology be like?

Comment: You mean, what would humans need for car crashes to be less fatal? I’m not sure you want to go down that road, so to speak. First, we’re talking millions of years - humans probably wouldn’t have cars by that point. Second, even if your story involves a radiation bomb that somehow mutates humans in a positive way without killing them, are you sure this would improve the situation rather than make people even more reckless? Don’t forget about the monetary side of car crashes - you may end up driving the country into bankruptcy, so to speak.

Comment: 5MPH fender-bender and *speed off a high cliff* are both car crashes.

Comment: Did you try googling this question before posting it here? There’s a ton of info about this out there. E.g. https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Qs69rICkeEU

Comment: Yes your are right this question was a bit too broad. What I wanted was if car for some some reason were not improving their safety standards according our physiology and remained in the 1980s style metal cars with very little safety features as today. In the word I imagined car crashes especially near imtersections somehow became more common  throughout generations without young and old car drivers seeing any new improvements. I know it is almost impossible for cars not to evolve change accordingly to driving contions such as weather and the like but what if this small chance were a reality.

Answer (score 3):

**Cars evolve way quicker than humans**.

So your question should be more "how would humans look if they were forcibly adapted to survive current-model car crashes?".

I'm afraid there are too many ways of doing that. Piercing trauma requires the more visible modifications, because you need some sort of biological armor.

Blunt trauma and acceleration damage, including diffuse axonal damage, can be ameliorated without too visible alterations by adding internal struts holding the organs together, and less incospicuously by adding what would look like layers of fat - and actually would be sacs of deceleration fluid. In short, biological airbags designed to spread decelerations over a slightly greater time scale.

Internal safety belts - bands of muscular and tendon tissue that would increase the natural reaction of "cringing" when expecting an impact.

But as the wise man said, "presence of spirit is good - *absence of body is better*". Increased reflexes, situational awareness and muscle sprint can allow you to survive an accident by *not being involved*.

If the worst happens, two modifications at almost the cellular level - *hibernation* to save energy, providing the first half of the [Vulcan healing trance](http://www.spockandsaavik.com/vulcans/VulcTelepathy.htm); and heightened regenerative powers, providing the second half.

So, no necessarily too visible modifications, but **if you need to**, you can make the shock-resistant humans look like this guy:

[image: Bibendum]

Answer (score 2):

Back in 2016 there was a project undertaken by the Transport Accident Commission of Australia. A trauma expert as well as the artist Patricia Piccinini collaborated to create 'Graham'. An artwork based somewhat in reality, the example of what physiological features that might be present in humans if they had evolved to withstand the forces involved in crashes.

---

Things such as the removing of the neck, which in turn sacrificed mobility were deemed necessary to make him more resilient to injury in the event of a crash.

[image]

---

As well as this, a larger cranium with surrounding crumple zones was introduced, also with the inclusion of more fatty tissue in the forehead to dampen impacts.

[image]

---

[Here is a link to the official website where you can explore the features in depth.](http://www.meetgraham.com.au/view-graham)